# Extjs: "this.view is null or not an object" error

Tags: extjs

I defined an Ext.window and there is a form inside it,and form contains a grid. when I am trying to show it via window.show() on a button click for the first time, its working fine,
But when I am clicking button for the second time "this.object is null or not an object, line:12" error is coming up.I am loading gridstore on click of button.
somebody plz help.

Comment: would need to see some code to know what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your closeAction for the window? If it is "destroy", which is the default, that will destroy all child elements. Try setting your window's "closeAction" to "hide".

Comment: window.close() will indeed close the window. His problem, however, seems to be on showing, *after* the first time. The default close action for a window is "destroy" which can cause issues if you have any child components, or even a variable reference to said object, that you attempt to reference later on.

Comment: If you use closeAction: 'close' which is the default, then the window cannot be reopened with show(). If you use use closeAction: 'hide' then the window can be shown and hidden but you must do this with hide() and show() calls.

I got this from other stackoverflow q's by the clue of Adam.

Thanks Adam. problem solved